# How to configure network for pluggable ethernet adapter under ArchLinux (systemd)?

Tags: networking, arch-linux, systemd

I have an USB ethernet adapter, but I am not sure how to configure it that the network is set up properly when the adapter is plugged in and out. Can I add something to netctl's config file to link it to the plugging of the hardware?

Comment: what does `lsusb`, `ifconfig`, and `dmesg` or `journalctl` show? You might also want to check [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#Device_names)

Comment: As it changes, I set the device name to enp2s3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is to create a udev rule which corresponds to the NIC you're plugging in and out.
plug in NIC

`udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/net/yourdeviceskernelname`

For example, `udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/net/eth1`

Make the udev rule match the output of above:

`sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/10-usb-nic
KERNEL=="yourdev*", ATTR{address}=="11:22:33:44:55:66", 
 NAME="usb"`

Then create a systemd-networkd unit to match the NIC.

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/network/10-usb.network 
[Match]
Name=yourdeviceskernelname 
[Network]
DHCP=v4 #for example`

See more on networkd  [here.](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-networkd#network_files)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a newer version of udev, you should be [fine](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) like when you turn on or off the wireless switch on your laptop.

If you want a script to be run automatically when you plug it in or out then you need to add a [udev rule](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/9311/print) to `/etc/udev/rules.d`

Comment: I just want the normal start/stop actions to be taken. Is this possible without writing a script that basically just does "systemctl stop netctl@enp2s3"? Because at the moment it is still considered active after unplugging.