# Renaming USB-LAN dongle iface for gui logon with gdm on Xorg

Tags: xorg, udev, network-interface, gdm3

*[4.13.9-1-ARCH  with gdm on Xorg]*

I saw quite a few posts (e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171881/how-to-configure-network-for-pluggable-ethernet-adapter-under-archlinux-systemd)) related to starting a service at boot or recognizing a usb drive. But here I want to rename the default Ethernet (wired) iface of my USB LAN dongle to ***net0*** at boot time, or at least BEFORE *systemd* service `netctl-ifplugd@net0.service` kicks in.

I first tried the Archlinux forum suggestion:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="net",ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="_mac_address_here_", NAME="net0"
```

**EDIT:**
The udev rule is executed when I log on to console. No prbm there.

If I wait say 1 minute before I log in via the gdm login menu, the iface is also correctly renamed

However if I log on via my gdm logon menu immediately after it appears on screen (that takes me about 3 to 5 seconds), then the interface is not renamed by the `udev`rule. When that happens, if I unplug and re-plug the USB LAN dongle, then the LAN interface gets renamed correctly.

However I want to avoid having to unplug and re-plug things every time I boot. Should be automatic.

Initially I thought that there was a pbm with my udev rule, then with a race condition between udev and network services kicking in. I now think this might be related to gdm on Xorg.

***Any clue anybody ?***

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is totally elsewhere. `udev` started in very early boot stage from the `initrd` image. `initrd` doesn't contains your manually created rules in `/etc`. Check it with `lsinitramfs /boot/initrd*`. 
You can add your rules file to initramfs, but the much more proper way is do as your distro suggests. For example in Debian there is a `/etc/initramfs-tools/` folder, where you have to put your custom files which will be in newly created initrds.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/mkinitcpio

Comment: No, that's off. Booting to console makes the problem disappear... everything else being the same.  Booting to `gdm` on `Xorg`  or rather immediately starting a login session in gdm after the gdm login screen appears seems to makes the renaming rule croak. On the other hand, if I wait say 1 or 2 minutes before I login via the gdm login screen, the udev rule kicks in and all works well (wired interface on dongle renamed + priority connectivity to the dongle). So all this is related to gdm, not to the init runtime.